# api.twitter.com にアクセスすると"Not authorized to use this endpoint."とエラーがでます

Tags: twitter

Twitter連携アプリを開発しています。
現在、Twitter連携アプリの作成にはdev.twitter.comから申請を行い承認を得ないと開発できませんが、
以前はapp.twitter.comから自由にアプリを作成することができ、その時に作ったアプリで開発していたので、申請の必要はないという認識でした。

OAuthによる連携のテストをしている最中にエラーが発生するので、OAuthのテストを使用とapp.twitter.com のアプリサイト( https://apps.twitter.com/app/XXXXXX/show ) にアクセスしたところ、上記"Not authorized to use this endpoint."というエラーが表示され、
アプリの設定が全くできない状態になっていました。
app.twitter.comにアクセスすると、自作アプリは空になっています。

app.twitter.comで作成したアプリはもう利用できなくなったのでしょうか？
こちら、なにか情報をお持ちの方がいたらご教授いただければ幸いです。

Answer (score 1):

2018年夏頃より、新たに開発者アカウントを申請しなければならなくなりました。

> 本日より、TwitterのAPIへのアクセスをご希望の全ての方に、developer.twitter.comにある新しいデベロッパーポータルで開発者アカウントを登録していただくことになります。いったん登録が承認されれば、developer.twitter.comで新たにアプリを開発したり既存のアプリを管理できるようになります。既存のアプリはapps.twitter.comでも引き続き管理できます。
>   https://blog.twitter.com/developer/ja_jp/topics/tools/2018/jp-new-developer-requirements-to-protect-our-platform.html

この申請を行うと、以前作成したアプリの管理や、新しいアプリを作成することも可能になります。自分は申請済みであり、 https://apps.twitter.com が以前と同様に表示されております。

Comment: コメントありがとうございます。
新しい開発者登録申請は行っておりますが、まだTwitter社からは何の返答も返ってきていません。
そのせいかもしれませんね……。
Twitter連携は諦めて、他のプラットフォームにて開発を進めようと思います。

Comment: この回答で解決できた場合、「解決済み」としてマークしていただけると今後同様の疑問がある方への参考になるのでそのようにお願いします。（未解決でしたらそのままでかまいません）

Comment: 実体験ベースですが、数日から数週間程度掛かったと記憶しています。気長に待つしかないですね。